# How to add navigation arrows to manually slide through posts?

Tags: posts, navigation, get-posts, slideshow

I have made this:

```
    <?php 

    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '5' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($args);
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        if($recent['post_status']=="publish"){
            echo '<li class="one_sixth">
            <a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   get_the_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"], 'thumbnail').'<div class="browse_category_name"> ' . $recent["post_title"]. '<div class="author"> <span>Author: </span> ' . get_the_author_meta('display_name', $recent["post_author"]). '</div></div></a></li> ';
        } else{
            echo '<li class="one_third">
            <a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a></li> ';
        }
         }
    ?>
```

So, what I want to achieve is... to make "navigation" arrows that will navigate one by one through these posts when you click on the arrow *(think like a carrousel)*, yet I have no idea how I can do this.

Where to start and what to do? Could someone help me out with it, please?

Answer (score 0):

Your code suggests that you want a list of 5 most recent posts. There is no navigation for a list, unless you use paging. It is different, when you display a single post page. Then you can navigate to 'next' or 'previous' post, with help of `the_post_navigation()` template function. See it in [Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_navigation/).

I've modified slightly your code, by adding `'post_status' => 'publish'` to `$args` array, so you don't need to check the status. Cleaned up incorrect nesting of HTML tags, as well. New code:

```
<?php 
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '5', 'post_status' => 'publish' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($args);
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ) {
        echo '<li class="one_sixth" style="list-style-position: outside;"><a href="' . get_permalink( $recent["ID"] ) . '" title="See ' . esc_attr( $recent["post_title"] ) . '" >' . $recent["post_title"] . '</a><br>Author: ' . get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $recent["post_author"] ) . '</li> ';
    }
    wp_reset_query();
    echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Thanks Frank, I appreciate it, yet I don't see how it fixes my problem. How would I need to use the_post_navigation, then? I can't imagine I am the only one who wants this?